# Prevent from coming back to login activity after pressign back button and restore application from background

Tags: android, android-activity

I prevented from coming back to login activity by this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
finish(); //Finish Login Activity
startActivity(intent); //start second Activity,
```

When user is on second activity and he pressed home button, app going to background, and when he restore it, the second activity appears - it's ok.
But when user press back button in second activity, app went to background and when he resore it - the login activity is again created and it is on foregoround.

What should I do to prevent login activity from being again created? Or maybe i should not finish the login activity and instead I should check if user is logged in - If it is, the I should show second activity?

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: 'Or maybe i should not finish the login activity and instead I should check if user is logged in - If it is, the I should show second activity'. You've answered it yourself.

Tho, you should finish the login activity because if you don't that might give the impression to your user that they have been logged out. But also use a check.

Comment: Then my root activity should be LoginActivity as I already have and in this activity check if user is logged in?
Or maybe my root activity should be the MainActivity and there in onCreate() method check if user must to log in and in this case call intent to LoginActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is Override the onBackPressed method like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

}
```

And put what ever you want it to do in that method.
Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest file add:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

to the login activity.

Comment: It doing the same thing as finish() method, so it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```